# react hooks and redux dispatch never stop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I am using the dispatch in my action:
but for some reason she never stops sending my dispatch I used a console.log in my response and I get nonstop

```
import {FETCH_FAIL,FETCH_LOADING,FETCH_SUCESS} from './actionType';
import api from '../../../services/api';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const FetchSucess = data  => (console.log(data),{
    type:FETCH_SUCESS,
    data
});
const FetchFailed = error  => ({
    type:FETCH_FAIL,
    error
});
const isLoadingFetch = () => ({type: FETCH_LOADING})


export default function AllProducts  () {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    dispatch(isLoadingFetch());
    // fetching data
    api.get('/products')
        .then( response => { dispatch(FetchSucess(response.data))})
        .catch( err => { dispatch(FetchFailed(err.message));});
}
```

and my container:

```
export default function Cards() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const classes2 = useStyles2();


    const loadProducts = getAllProducts();


    const products = useSelector(state => state.data.filteredProducts);



    return (

        <div className="App">
        <Container maxWidth="md" className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container md={4} spacing={1} ></Grid>
        <Grid container md={8} spacing={1} alignItems={"center"}>
        {products.map(product => (
            <Grid item lg={4} md={4} sm={12} xs={12}>
      <Card className={classes2.card}>
          <CardMedia
            className={classes2.media}
            image={
              "https://www.theclutch.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/skins-csgo-neymar.jpg"
            }
          />
          <CardContent className={classes2.content}>
            <Typography
              className={classes2.name}
              variant={"h6"}
              gutterBottom
            >
              {product.name}
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              className={classes2.price}
              variant={"h1"}
            >
             {util.formatCurrency(product.price)}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
            </Grid> 
        ))}
        </Grid>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
}
```

But at console.log my dispatch doesn't stop running all the time
I don't know if this is correct
he sends dispatch all the time and never to

I don't know if this is normal, if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the component is re-rendered upon loading the data from AllProducts().

`const loadProducts = getAllProducts();`
This needs to be called only once.
You need to make use of useEffect (and pass the second argument as an empty array) which is similar to componentDidMount.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Cards() {
        useEffect(() => {
          // This will be invoked only once.
          getAllProducts();
        }, []);

        const classes = useStyles();
        const classes2 = useStyles2();

        const products = useSelector(state => state.data.filteredProducts);



        return (

            <div className="App">
            <Container maxWidth="md" className={classes.root}>
            <Grid container md={4} spacing={1} ></Grid>
            <Grid container md={8} spacing={1} alignItems={"center"}>
            {products.map(product => (
                <Grid item lg={4} md={4} sm={12} xs={12}>
          <Card className={classes2.card}>
              <CardMedia
                className={classes2.media}
                image={
                  "https://www.theclutch.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/skins-csgo-neymar.jpg"
                }
              />
              <CardContent className={classes2.content}>
                <Typography
                  className={classes2.name}
                  variant={"h6"}
                  gutterBottom
                >
                  {product.name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                  className={classes2.price}
                  variant={"h1"}
                >
                 {util.formatCurrency(product.price)}
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
                </Grid> 
            ))}
            </Grid>
            </Container>
          </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: hi i  got this error with this: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: